# How to modify a text view in app on user request

Tags: android, string, textview

I'm trying to make a app with some nice features. One of them is :

I want to modify the text that you  see in my app on user request. By this I mean if you  see the MENU name in my app and want to display it as MAIN MENU or MY MENU etc you press a button, open an edit interface, write the name,click ok and that's it, text changed.

Here is little part of my aplication, it's shows up Slide to change the brightness, but user want to change it to “Brighness changer” .  Any ideeas how to do that ?

```
   <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Slide to change the brightness"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
```

I know that all my names are saved in a strings.xml file , problems is that i don't want to recompile my app everytime user will make a change..that's the main problem. I need a way to do it to avoid this .

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You store the string they want to use in a shared preference.  When you display this layout, read the value from the shared preference and call setText on the TextView to set the text.  Use the existing string as the default, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I understood first part, problems is i don't know/don't understandt this " when you display this layout " . What you mean by this ?  Where do i display it ? I mean how to i intervene to make it read the text that user will input ?   I understood how shared preference works don't worry . If you can explain a little more it would be nice . Thank you in advance.